# Datatable reorder get backs to its original position

Tags: javascript

```
$(tableid)
      .DataTable({
        "data": jsonData,
        deferRender: true,
        "scrollY": scorllY,
        "scrollX":false,
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "scroller" :true,
        "paging":true,
        "language": {
            "zeroRecords": emptyLabel
        },
        "autoWidth": false,
        order: [[5, "asc"]],
        rowReorder:{update: true,dataSrc:'shareclassno'},
```

Rows are getting back to its original position. For this I am using datatable initialization like above.
If I put `rowReorder:{update:false}` property it reverts rows to origin position & for `rowReorder:{update:false}` it reorders rows but `row-reordered` event not get called. Anything missing or wrong?